# Safe DHW with PV

Tags: batteries, inverter, solar-cell, solar-charge-controller

as the title says, i'm trying to heat water for domestic use via PV. From my research so far, the most popular suggestion seems to be solar thermal. That isn't the right option for me.

Pros of solar thermal:

- smaller surface area

Pros of solar PV:

- cheaper (depending on the solution)
- no/fewer moving parts
- ease of installation: channels for PV cabling already installed, that's not the case for solar thermal
- i already have an AC immersion heater in my hot water tank
- in the future i plan to install a proper 5kw PV grid-tie system so i could reuse the panels
- the big one: i don't have to worry about overheating issues in the summer when i don't use hot water for a couple of days

Tank's 200 liters, and my hot water energy demand is roughly 8 kWh/day, so a 700-1000 watt system would suffice. Ideally i'd like to use an off-the-shelf solution as much as possible, not the custom microcontroller route, that said, hooking up a temperature probe to a relay through arduino etc isn't a problem. So far i entertained 3 options:

- simplest/cheapest is to get a DC immersion heater and match it to PV panels to be close to MPP. I'd need a temp probe and a relay/mosfet to cut power when water temperature reaches upper limit. I'm worried about the safety of switching relatively high voltage DC current, also about potential electrolysis happening in the tank, not sure what kind of damage could that do. I know AC immersion heaters have a protective outer shell and ground protection, which wouldn't be the case for DC
- use a solar charge controller like this one (https://www.epever.com/product/tracer-an-10-40a-mppt-charge-controller/) and hook only a properly rated DC immersion heater up to it. This gives me more efficiency because MPPT, but the questions of cutoff and electrolysis are still there (unless these controllers have safety mechanisms in them). I also don't know if these controllers can work without batteries connected, but i'd like to avoid batteries in the system.
- use an off-grid solar inverter that already outputs 240v, and hook it up to the existing immersion heater (AC 240v, 2500W). This is the priciest option, but easiest to install since the immersion heater is already in place, it has internal thermostatic control for cutoff and is grounded, although i don't know how an off-grid inverter handles ground protection. The question is, can off-grid inverters work without batteries hooked up? Every one i saw has battery terminals in addition to the AC plugs.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Where are you located. See www.gaisma.com for actual sunshine hours per day by month. Varies with location but typicalish is ,2 hours in winter and 6 in summer.

Comment: I live in Romania. I can adapt the required output to serve my needs, and i have other another source for DHW (natural gas), trying to reduce the bills

Comment: Not sure if you appreciate how much smaller the direct heating area would be ... not just a bit smaller, but about 1/4 the PV area.

Comment: PV isn't cheaper and doesn't have fewer moving parts.

Comment: immersion heaters should work equally well on AC or DC